# Request sent is taking too long. why would that be?

Tags: node.js, http, nginx, xmlhttprequest

"Request sent" is taking nearly 3+ seconds.

client code:

```
JQ.ajax({
  url: '/test',
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSONdata,
  success: function(response) {
  console.log('done');
   }
});
```

server code:

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res){
  res.send(req.body)
});
```

dataLength is 865853 ( as seen from headers )

server is running Nginx behind which NodeJS server is running.

Want to understand why this is happening and ways to reduce it.
[image: Example]

Its a post request. adding the headers image:
[image: Headers]

Comment: Do you have logs from NGINX?  Node?  Do you know the timing of when things are hitting those components?

Comment: May be you're sending too much payload and it takes time to upload..

Comment: Remove the entire payload and check how much time it takes then?

Comment: its lesss than 10ms with little payload.

Comment: Then it defines the problem, uploading takes time depending upon the internet speed. You should not worry about it

Comment: I doubt it. Just tested my Internet speed. Its 190Mbps for upload. For the given dataLength, 865853, it shouldnt take 3.5s

Comment: Check that your Nginx reverse proxy is not buffering the request (proxy_buffering off)

Comment: @Learner: if you try to access the node module directly does it take same time ? If yes then there is no issue in Nginx, if no then there should be some limit configured in Nginx which is taking some time or might be any thing else.

Comment: @regilero tried that. no improvement. Thanks for all the responses. :) i think the issue here is the server's network bandwidth. will check that and keep you guys posted.

Comment: @Learner did you manage to figure this out that what is the root casue or what is the efficient way to send heavy json post body?

Answer (score 1):

> Request sent is taking too long. why would that be?

It could be anything.

> Want to understand why this is happening and ways to reduce it.

There may be lots of reasons. Without seeing even a single line of your code it's impossible to tell you what's wrong with it. You may be using blocking functions, you may be calling external services, you may do too much work in the main process, you may be blocking the event loop, you may forget to handle errors, you may be doing a number of things wrong in your application and you may have misconfigured your reverse proxy, you may be using wrong ports, wrong hosts, the network may be slow, routers may be overloaded, packets may be lost, you can have memory leaks, swap trashing, CPU maxed out etc.

Comment: The OP is saying `Request sent is taking time`, the issues you explained will cause the `response` to delay, not the request